# Using PagerAdapter to handle Multiple Fragments per page

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I've seen many a tutorial for the standard `FragmentTabsPager` implementation, where a single `Fragment` is on each page. I'm attempting to combine the `FragmentLayoutSupport` example (ListFragment on left, details `Fragment` on right) with the pager example.

Here is the `getItem()` method in `FragmentTabsPager` from the v4 support library.

```
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
    }
```

In order to support multiple `Fragments` per page (not nested, rather side by side), would it be a case of programmatically declaring a layout (e.g. `LinearLayout`) in my overridden version of this method, instantiating the two `Fragments`, and adding them as children, returning the `LinearLayout`? (In the case of a portrait orientation, returning the `LinearLayout` with only one `Fragment`.)

Is it sufficient to override this method alone, or is that a naive approach to the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the `FragmentPagerAdapter`, create your own adapter that returns a `View` (in your case the `LinearLayout`).

Comment: what else would need to be changed though? Is there a reason not to extend FragmentPagerAdapter and override the get view?

Comment: Well `FragmentPagerAdapter` is designed to work with single fragments, and you want multiple. Implement the necessary methods of `PagerAdapter` (`instantiateItem()`) and plug it in your pager. You could do something like `MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener' to handle page creation and switching in a single class.

Comment: Is there a technical or semantic reason not to do `MultipleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` - if I override the `getView` to return another layout with multiple fragments, why is this not desired? (this is the crux of my question, I understand I can't use the FragmentPagerAdapter in its current form.)

Comment: Have you looked at the code? The bulk of `FragmentPagerAdapter` is the `instantiateItem()` and `destroyItem()` implementations. If you override those, it's pretty much the same as writing a new one. Plus you need to implement the abstract `getItem()` which returns a fragment. What will you return, `null`? As for semantics, read the JavaDoc: 'Implementation of a PagerAdapter that represents each page as a Fragment'. Since your pages won't be single fragments, this is clearly the wrong class to use.